# LED not lighting up on my DE10Lite verilog FPGA design

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to make use of the **FP_FUNCTIONS Intel FPGA IP** to multiply two inputs, and display the output on LEDs. However, my codes couldn't light the LED up.

```
module multiplier (A, B, Clock, Reset, Zreg, LEDR);
    parameter n = 10;
    input [n-1:0] A, B;
    output reg [n-1:0] Zreg;
    input Clock, Reset;
    reg [n-1:0] Areg, Breg;
    output [n-1:0] LEDR;
    
    wire [n-1:0] Z;
    
    multiply mult (.clk(Clock), .areset(Reset), .a(Areg), .b(Breg), .q(Z));

    assign LEDR [9:0] = Zreg;
    
    always @(posedge Reset or posedge Clock)
    begin
        if (Reset == 1)
        begin
            Areg <= 0; Breg <= 0; Zreg <= 0;
        end
        else
        begin
            Areg <= A; Breg <= B; Zreg <= Z;
        end

    end
endmodule
```

In the code above, I named the **FP_FUNCTIONS Intel FPGA IP** module as 'multiply'.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you simulated your design?

Comment: If you multiply it directly (x = a * b), does it work?

Comment: I managed to fix it by reloading the IPs. Still have no idea why it failed because I always used the same IP parameters.
Multiplying it as a * b does work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reloading the IPs.